# fixed point iteration divergence.

Tags: numerical-methods, fixed-point-theorems

We know that if $g(x)$ is continuous over $[a,b]$ and
$g(x) \in [a,b],  \forall x \in [a,b]$ and
$|g'(x)| < 1 , \forall x \in [a,b]$

then fixed point iteration will converge only into 1 point $p$, $p \in [a,b] , g(p) = p$.

So my question is, do we have any way to know if the iteration will diverge for any $x_0$?
I mean this theorem is only one-sided which means if 1 of these conditions doesn't occur we can't conclude if the iteration will converge or diverge, so is there any theorem that can tell us if we'll converge or diverge ?

**Edit:**
I'm looking for some condition or theorem that if this condition or theorem occurs then for any given $x_0$ the iteration will diverge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, if $g:[a.b]\longrightarrow[a,b]$  is continuous your required divergence for any initial point is impossible because $g$ will have at least fixed point $p$ and $p = g(p) = g(g(p)) = \cdots$

EDIT:

Lat be $F$ the set of fixed points of $g$ and $E =\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty g^{-n}(F)$. If all the fixed points of $g$ are repelling (for all $p\in F$, $|g'(x)| > 1$ for all $x$ in a neighborhood of $p$), then for any $x_0\in[a,b]\setminus E$, the sequence $x_0$, $g(x_0)$, $g(g(x_0))$, $\dots$ diverges.

Proof: Suppose $(x_n) = (g^n(x_0))$ converges. Only can converge to some fixed point $p$. Let be $(p-\epsilon,p+\epsilon)$ a repelling neighborhood. Then, for some $n$, $x_n,x_{n+1}\in(p-\epsilon,p+\epsilon)$ with $p<x_{n+1}<x_n$ or $x_n<x_{n+1}<p$. Then, by the MVT
$$|x_{n+1} - p| = |g(x_n) - g(p)| = |g'(\xi)(x_n - p)| > |x_n - p|,$$
contradiction.

Comment: well thats not true at all...
example: $g(x) = 3 , x \in [2,5]$
$x0 = 5$
so $g(x0) = 4 , x1 = 4$
$g(x1) = 4 , x2 = 4$
and you can see you will never converge into your fixed point...

Comment: you can clearly see when $|g'(x)| >= 1$ it might converge and might not.
im looking for some condition that will assure me divergence of the iteration.

Comment: @Itay.V $g(x) = 3$ for all $x\in[2,5]$?

Comment: yeah, constant function.

Comment: @Itay.V What? If you have $g(x)=3$ and $x_0=5$ then $g(x_0)=3=x_1$ and you have convergence to the fixed point in one step. Note that the point made in this answer is quite general: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brouwer_fixed-point_theorem

Comment: @lan
what ?? what are you talking about ??
g(x) = 3 means for every x you will get 3 
while g(x) = x means for every x you will get x..

Comment: @Itay.V, are you asking divergence for *all* initial point $x_0$ of for *some* initial point $x_0$?

Comment: @Itay.V You have $g(x)=3$. You put in $x_0=5$. You get $g(x_0)=3$. You set that to be $x_1$. You put that in, and you get $g(x_1)=3$ again. Now you are sitting at the fixed point of $g(x)$, i.e. $x=3$, forever. "$g(x)=x$" does not necessarily mean "for every $x$ you will get $x$", it depends on the context, i.e. on whether $x$ is intended to be a universally quantified variable or a fixed constant. When we are talking about fixed points, such an $x$ is a fixed constant.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla 
im looking for condition that will assure divergence for ANY initial point x0
(except the fixed point it self, x0 = fixed point, thats not intresting..)

Comment: @Ian yeah my bad, that was bad example indeed.. but i would like to know about divergence condition if you know any (:

Comment: @Itay.V, then, edit your question.

Comment: @Itay.V Are you asking "what is a condition on $g$ such that for all $x_0$ not equal to the fixed point, fixed point iteration started at $x_0$ diverges?", or "what is a condition on $g$ and $x_0$ such that fixed point iteration started at $x_0$ diverges?"? (Neither one of these is expressed by your question as written, by the way.)

Comment: @Ian 
that first one:
what is a condition on $g$ such that for all $x0$ not equal to the fixed point, fixed point iteration started at $x0$ diverges?

Comment: @Itay.V, all the fixed points $p$ are repelling: $|g'(p)|>1$.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla
any chance for a proof ?

Comment: @Itay.V, wait until tomorrow.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla i will (:
thanks in advance.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla I don't understand the meaning of your set $E$. I'm also a bit skeptical about your assessment: I believe it is possible to land exactly on a repelling fixed point from far away. It is of course impossible to "nontrivially converge" to it, i.e. to have a sequence of *positive* distances from it that go to zero.

Comment: @Ian, "I believe it is possible to land exactly on a repelling fixed point from far away." True, and this is exactly the reason to exclude $E$. If points of $E$ were accepted the contradiction in $|x_{n+1} - p| = |g(x_n) - g(p)| = |g'(\xi)(x_n - p)| > |x_n - p|$ fails.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla Oh, I see, and $g^{-n}$ means preimage, not "image of inverse". That makes sense. Nice.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla ok, first of all I really appreciate the answer, I just have a few questions if you could elaborate on some details please. 1) if we supposed that Xn = (gn (x0)) converges then shouldn't (p-epsilon,p+eps) should be convergence neighborhood? 2) why Xn and Xn+1 should be both bigger then p or smaller, if they are In the neighborhood they can be 1 from the right and 1 from the left (I think..) 3) could you elaborate on you last equation please (G'(xi)(Xn-p))?

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla *1) if we supposed that Xn = (gn(x0)) converges then should (p-eps,p+eps) be convergence neighborhood?

Comment: @Itay.V, (1) the set of initial points that produce a convergent sequence can be greater. (2) The important fact is that for some (actually many!) $n$, $0<|x_{n+1} - p| < |x_n - p|$ if $(x_n)\to p$ and $\forall n\ x_n\ne p$. (3) See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem.